# Formatting a database generated XML document

Tags: php, sql, xml, mysqli

I am using the following code to generate an XML document from an sql database, which at the moment is working fine.

```
<?php

include ("config/init.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM locations"; 
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli_conn, $query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error()); 
//Top of xml file
$_xml .="<markers>"; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $_xml .="<marker>"; 
        $_xml .="<id>".$row['id']."</id>"; 
        $_xml .="<name>".$row['name']."</name>"; 
        $_xml .="<address>".$row['address']."</address>"; 
        $_xml .="<lat>".$row['lat']."</lat>";
        $_xml .="<lng>".$row['lng']."</lng>";  
        $_xml .="</marker>"; 
        } 
        $_xml .="</markers>"; 
//Parse and create an xml object using the string
$xmlobj=new SimpleXMLElement($_xml);

//write to an XML file
$xmlobj->asXML('locations.xml');
?>
```

This creates a XML document called 'locations.xml' which looks like this:

```
<markers>
 <marker>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>NAME</name>
  <address>ADDRESS</address>
  <lat>23.234567</lat>
  <lng>-1.987654</lng>
 </marker>
</markers>
```

However I need it to be in a format like this:

```
<markers>
<marker name="NAME" lat="23.234567" lng="-1.987654" address="ADDRESS" />
</markers>
```

What is the best what of going about this? I'm am relatively new to doing this sort of thing so any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Php has several XML Manipulation objects.  In my experience, DOM is best for writing and SimpleXML is best for reading.

```
<?php

$xmlObj = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xmlObj->formatOutput = true;

$root = $xmlObj->createElement('markers') ;
$root = $xmlObj->appendChild( $root );

$row = array('id'=>5677,'name'=>'Name','address'=>'404 Not Found Rd Ste ', 'lat'=>'10.', 'lng'=>'50.');

for ( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
    $currentRow = $xmlObj->createElement('marker');
    foreach ( $row as $key => $value )
    {  $currentRow->setAttribute($key,$value.$i);  }

    $root->appendChild( $currentRow );
}

print $xmlObj->saveXML();
?>
```